# Can't build Flutter App with Gradle problems (Release APK)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have an outdated App developed in Flutter. I need to update it to new gradle version and new packages version. With new Gradle I need new Kotlin version and I decided use Gradle 8.0 and Kotlin 1.8.10.

In debug mode all works fine when I make all the changes but the App doesn't installs on my phone or emulator...

Here is my build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" //1.8.10
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In first I run the build and it launch me an exception with some packages (deprecated APIs, incompatibility). Here is the output:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/llomen/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.6.9/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/llomen/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_mailer-2.1.1/android/src/main/java/com/dataxad/flutter_mailer/FlutterMailerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/llomen/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/video_player_android-2.4.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/Messages.java:44: error: pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 8
    if (exception instanceof FlutterError error) {
                                          ^
  (use -source 16 or higher to enable pattern matching in instanceof)
/Users/llomen/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/video_player_android-2.4.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/QueuingEventSink.java:62: error: pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 8
      } else if (event instanceof ErrorEvent errorEvent) {
                                             ^
  (use -source 16 or higher to enable pattern matching in instanceof)
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I know how to update the Gradle with android studio and I decided to run the update assistant and it updates successfully. But when I build the app it throws me another exception similar like this:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
```

I don't know what is failing here if I have the updated gradle version to 8.0
Anyways I change the "namespaces" and deleted all the "package" field in manfiest of all my flutter packages (+30) and it seems to work but doesn't. I'm so blind with that exceptions and all the info I've searched here or in official doc doesn't works to me

Any help is accepted, thanks!

Comment: From the error description, it appears that the Gradle version you are using is not compatible with the JAVA version you are using. Then try changing the JAVA version to at least version 11, like this:
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11

jvmTarget = '11'

Comment: @MarcoDomingos I've tried with 11 and 17 but nothing. Thanks anyways

Comment: Is the error message still the same even after updating the java version?